# EL can't handle a single character before an underscore?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, javabeans, el

I am using EL to pull an object from a bean stored in the session.

The object is question is called P_COV_MOULT and is declared as follows:

```
this.P_COV_MOULT = new FormField("F_B_P_COV_MOULT","");
```

And is accessed via a getter method like so:

```
public FormField getP_COV_MOULT() {
    return P_COV_MOULT;
}
```

Which was generated by NetBeans.

I appreciate that the usage of all caps separated by underscores does not fit the naming conventions for non constants, but it's useful for semantic value.

I have many other properties stored in this same bean, and am pulling those all fine and have been for a while.

However, with this P_COV_MOULT and other properties that are in the format of 
multiple underscore separated values but with the first one being a single character, I get a javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException.

The objects/properties are stored in exactly the same way as all the rest, but they just can't be found.

I've tried inserting a separate method getp_COV_MOULT(), on the assumtion that it was converting the name in EL to a getter incorrectly (or correctly) and not calling getP_COV_MOULT(), but instead calling a different method, such as getp_COV_MOULT(), but that didn't work.

Here is the EL:

```
<input type="text" name="${findingBiometrics.P_COV_MOULT.name}" id="${findingBiometrics.P_COV_MOULT.name}" value="${findingBiometrics.P_COV_MOULT.value}"
                                           ${findingBiometrics.P_COV_MOULT.readonlyState} ${findingBiometrics.P_COV_MOULT.disabledState} size="5" />
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And what happens in you use `p_COV_MOULT` in the EL expressions?

Comment: @JB Nizet Good question, I'm embarrassed to say I never tried that. It appears to work great, and makes sense, thankyou. I appreciate this is a comment, but you answered the question in one, so if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: NilsH alread posted it as an answer, so accept his answer.

Comment: @JB Nizet So he has, thank-you, I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is that property names start with a small letter. So if the property name is `theProperty`, then the getter is named `getTheProperty`. So if you have a getter called `getP_COV_MOULT`, I would expect the EL property to be `p_COV_MOULT`. However, your naming is pretty weird, so I'm not 100% sure it would work.

Comment: Thankyou, this works great. I appreciate I should be following the naming convention, but it's weird project, with weird requirements.

Comment: Good :) I was typing on my phone, so it was a little slow. Didn't see the comment from @JBNizet until I had posted.